# Why do we do functional analysis over $\mathbb{C}$? Why is algebraic completeness so important?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples

From the perspective of functional analysis, why is it that we so often focus on vector spaces (Hilbert, Banach, whatever) over $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$? Many of these objects obviously have natural real and complex versions, but I don't yet understand why we spend so much time on complex Hilbert spaces or $*$-algebras or whatever, when my naive guess would be that the theory is simpler over $\mathbb{R}$ and we could then extrapolate from there to the complex setting.

I assume that algebraic completeness factors into the equation, but while I can see the importance of working over $\mathbb{C}$ in the finite-dimensional world of linear algebra, where we have niceties like characteristic polynomials, polynomials seem themselves rather "finitary" in nature, and seem to often kinda disappear once we move to the infinite-dimensional setting. Where in the finite-dimensional setting we can say, "every matrix has a characteristic polynomial, so it must have at least one eigenvalue over $\mathbb{C}$ because the characteristic polynomial will split", once we move to even a separable space like $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$, we can lose that luxury. My assumption would be that when polynomials become scarce, the ability to solve them because less vital.

One counterexample to this I could think of would be the density of $1$-dimensional representations in $L^1(G)$ for a compact group $G$. If I want to study $S^1$, I have to study the continuous homomorphisms $S^1 \to \mathbb{T} : = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 1 \}$. I can't get away with studying just the homomorphisms into the real part of $\mathbb{T}$ because that'd only leave me with the trivial homomorphism. I can still study real-valued functions on $S^1$ with Fourier analysis, but I have to drop down from the complex world to the real, not the other way around. I am starting with $\left\{ e^{2 \pi i k t} : k \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$ and coming back to the real-valued functions on $S^1$ from there.

What are some other examples of results or concepts in analysis where the complex view of the field is indispensable when compared to the merely real?

Comment: When you are looking at the spectrum of an operator, it's nice when your operator has a spectrum.

Comment: And to add to that point, you don't even need to go into infinite-dimensions to see the benefits. Have you tried using the real version of the Jordan Normal Form? It's a waste of time.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I'm pretty embarrassed that I forgot such a simple example. But why is the spectrum defined over $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ in the infinite-dimensional setting? Why are those complex points also important?

Comment: @user780985 I think I more or less addressed that. The Jordan form is related to the characteristic polynomial splitting (requiring algebraic completeness), which requires a (finite-dimensional) matrix, but when you go the infinite-dimensional setting, you no longer have those characteristic polynomials. If algebraic completeness is about solving polynomials, then what polyomials are we solving in infinite dimensions?

Comment: @AJY this is a rather philosophical question. Why something is important? It isn't. Or maybe it is as important as you believe it is. Anyway the driving force behind complex analysis is physics, where it has lots of applications. From purely mathematical perspective there's no reason to treat $\mathbb{C}$ better than $\mathbb{R}$ or anything else.

Comment: @freakish I don't think it's an especially "philosophical" point. A lot of algebra takes on a very different flavor if you turn from algebraically complete fields to algebraically incomplete fields. Plenty of theory is correct in one world and completely off-base in the other. I can see plainly enough why algebraic completeness is important in algebra, but I'm less clear how it cuts into analysis.

Comment: It's not just algebraic completeness. Complex analysis has many powerful tools which are simply wrong in real analysis, and this has nothing to do with completeness. When you talk about Banach algebras over $\mathbb{C}$ you can extend the definitions of holomorphic functions to Banach algebras, prove using Lioville's theorem that a spectrum is always non empty (as was mentioned before). Then we can go farther and define $C^*$-algebras which are also important. If we only work over $\mathbb{R}$ we are much more limited.